# How to exclude admins from receiving user relationship requests?

Tags: users

The title seems to be clear enough. I am wondering how the site administrators can be excluded from [user-relationship](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) requests (in D6.22).

It seems to be defective in the module's settings: While there is a 'Role Receive' option there which states:

> You may choose which roles are allowed to receive this relationship.
>   If none are selected, all roles are allowed to receive the
>   relationship

But while I've chosen roles other that 'site administrator', but the site administrators still receive the unwelcommed requests.

Hoping to circumvent this problem, I've installed [User Relationship Limits](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationship_limits) but the admininstrator role is not among the 'Role Limits'!

So I appreciate your hints to resolve this issue.